# EncodeDecodeMux - Samsung Devices - Tested on S6 Edge and S5

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, codec, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

Reference: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java

I am using the above code to encode/decode/mux in order to make a video with lower resolution and bitrate. 
Its working perfectly fine on all the resolutions including 4k videos on nexus5, LG g3, one plus.

But samsung devices show inappropriate behavior.

- If i take 4k video (3840x2160) as input and want to lower its resolution to 1920x1080 i get exception.
- If i take 4k video (3840x2160) as input and want to lower its resolution to 1280x720 i still get exception.
- It works perfectly fine if i set target resolution to 640x360.

I think that might be related to codec issues on samsung devices.

Following is the code snippet

```
 MediaCodec encoder = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecInfo.getName());
        encoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        surfaceReference.set(encoder.createInputSurface());
        encoder.start();

  MediaCodec decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(getMimeTypeFor(inputFormat));
        decoder.configure(inputFormat, surface, null, 0);
decoder.start();
```

Following statement causes the exception

```
decoder.configure(inputFormat, surface, null, 0);
```

Following is the stack trace

```
I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.AVC.Encoder] Now Executing
03-15 14:35:23.801 25357-26008/com.test I/ACodec:  [] Now uninitialized
03-15 14:35:23.801 25357-26036/com.test I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
03-15 14:35:23.811 25357-26036/com.test I/ACodec: can't find wfdsink-exynos-enable
03-15 14:35:23.811 25357-26036/com.test E/ACodec:  configureCodec multi window instance fail  appPid : 25357
03-15 14:35:23.811 25357-26036/com.test E/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] configureCodec returning error -1021
03-15 14:35:23.811 25357-26036/com.test E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001001, internalError -1021)
03-15 14:35:23.811 25357-26035/com.test E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xfffffc03, actionCode 0, while in state 3
03-15 14:35:23.811 25357-26008/com.test E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0xfffffc03, resetting...
03-15 14:35:23.811 25357-26036/com.test I/ACodec:  [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now uninitialized
03-15 14:35:23.811 25357-26008/com.test I/ACodec:  [] Now uninitialized
03-15 14:35:23.811 25357-26036/com.test I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
```

Comment: Samsung is always a struggle. Best of luck!

Comment: Could be a hardware limitation, e.g. insufficient bandwidth in the codec part to handle decoding at 4K and encoding at 720p. The error message is typically unhelpful.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it seems that some Samsung devices may just have problems with the Exynos decoder. I was getting almost the same error messages you were seeing. The solution was complex but seems to have fixed the problem.

I replaced these 2 lines of code:

```
decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
decoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
```

With this method:

```
private MediaCodec configDecoder(MediaFormat format, Surface surface) {

    if (format == null || surface == null) {
        return null;
    }

    MediaCodec codec;
    String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
    MediaCodecList list = new MediaCodecList(MediaCodecList.REGULAR_CODECS);
    MediaCodecInfo[] infos = list.getCodecInfos();

    for (MediaCodecInfo info : infos) {

        CodecCapabilities capabilities;
        boolean formatSupported;

        // does codec support this mime type
        try {
            capabilities = info.getCapabilitiesForType(mime);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
            continue;
        }

        // does codec support his video format
        try {
            formatSupported = capabilities.isFormatSupported(format);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
            continue;
        }

        // can we configure it successfully
        if (formatSupported) {
            // try decoder
            try {
                codec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(info.getName());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                codec.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
                // configure() failed
                codec.release();
                continue;
            } catch (IllegalStateException ignored) {
                // configure() failed
                codec.release();
                continue;
            }
            // configure() successful
            return codec;
        }
    } // end of for loop

    // no decoder found
    return null;
}
```

Usually, to get a codec, you just call

```
MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mimeType)
```

or

```
MediaCodecList.findDecoderForFormat(format)
```

But this only gives you one option. Using the method above, you have more find-grained control over which codec you use. For instance, you could easily filter out all the *Exynos* codecs by adding

```
if (!info.getName().contains("Exynos"))
```

or something similar.

Anyway, hopefully this helps someone else in the future. It frustrated me for several days.

As a final note, my older devices worked fine with the old code, and the new code uses some Lollipop and higher methods, so my final solution looked like this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    decoder = configDecoder(format, surface);
} else {
    decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
    decoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
}
```

Watching the code run, it still uses Exynos much of the time, but when the configure() failures for some reason, it's nice to see it seemlessly moving to the next codec.